# Pointing google domain subdomain at an aws api-gateway API

Tags: amazon-api-gateway, google-domains

I have a google managed domain, and a lambda based api in aws api gateway. I want to create a sub domain that points to api gateway.

I created an ACM Certificate using aws certificate manager. This included creating CNAME credentials, which were imported into my google domain. AWS performed the handshake and validate the credentials.

I then created a custom domain in aws api gateway. I named it the same as the acm certificate's domain, api.coopstools.com, and attached it to the acm certificate. I then added the base path mapping to the API I created in lambda.

(as a side note, I can hit and use the API using the default url that is provided when I staged the API, so I know it's up and running)

I did this all more than 24 hours ago (knowing that it sometimes takes a while).

I've tried hitting the endpoint to no avail, just receiving a "Could not resolve host: ..." message.

The dig result shows that the core domain has authority, but none of the subdomain show up.

Am I missing a piece in here? Or, are there any specific pieces of information needed to help me?

Thanks for any help,

P.S. I apologize for not giving more specific details as I still haven't figured out some of the security settings, and don't want to over expose anything.

EDIT: The issue was fixed thanks to @Joseph. All I had to due was the take the Target Domain Name from the custom domain in api gateway, and use it to create a new CNAME entry in the Custom Resource Records of Google Domains (the same place I put the original CNAME for creating the ACM certificate). It took about a minute and a half for everything to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need another CNAME record pointing at your default API gateway domain.  So for instance, if your custom domain is `my.domain.com`, you need to add a CNAME to `my.domain.com` that points to `abcdefg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` or whatever your API gateway domain currently is.

This is separate from the CNAME you already added, because that one was just to verify your *ownership* of the domain in question.  With ACM, the verification CNAME sits on a subdomain of the domain you're verifying, so if you're verifying `my.domain.com` then the CNAME goes on e.g. `_abcdef123456.my.domain.com`.  Which, obviously, doesn't help people who are trying to look up the address of `my.domain.com`.

Comment: Just to clarify, what had already been done: 1) Created a certificate using AWS Certificate manager 2) Created a custom domain in the API gateway, imported the certificate, AND defined at least 1 API mapping 3) Added a CNAME entry in Google Domains where name was the subdomain name (e.g. `my` for `my.domain.com`) and data was something like `asdf.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com.` Basically the invoke url without `https` but with a `.` at the end. The final step they forgot was to add a second CNAME entry for the certificate.

Comment: See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-google-domains.html  It is for `amplify` but it shows the entries needed.

Comment: Finally, there are currently some restrictions on certificate region. If you are using a `HTTP API` (cheaper) you have to use a regional endpoint type and your certificate region has to match your API region. If you are using `REST API` you can choose `regional` or `edge` endpoint. If you want a `edge` endpoint then your certificate region has to be `us-east-1` https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-domain-name-amazon-api-gateway/ And as always, these rules may change tomorrow ...